# What is the specific name for basic data types?

Tags: terminology, abstract-data-types

What is the specific name for data types such as integer, string, real (the basic ones)?

Comment: What do you mean by "specific name"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are called **[primitive data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_data_type)**.

(This is a pretty basic find in Wikipedia's [article on data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_type#Classes_of_data_types).)